# c outputing weird symbols when pairing chars with %c or %s

Tags: c

im new to C and im trying to build a tic tac toe game but i encoutered a problem i cant seem to fix the output of the place - place9 chars are being printed as weird signs like heart symbols ive tried changing the var from %c to %s but that gives even a worse output. the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main() {

char mark = "X";
char mark2 = 'O';
int choice;
char place = '1';
char place2 = '2';
char place3 = '3';
char place4 = '4';
char place5 = '5';
char place6 = '6';
char place7 = '7';
    char place8 = '8';
    char place9 = '9';
printf("please enter a position  1-9:\n ");

scanf_s("%d", &choice);





if (choice == 1 &&  place == '1')

    mark = place;
else
{
    goto jump2;
}
jump2:
if (choice == 2 && place2 == '2')

    mark = place2;
else
{
    goto jump3;
}
jump3:
if (choice == 3 && place3 == '3')

    mark = place3;
else
{
    goto jump4;
}
jump4:
if (choice == 4 && place4 == '4')

    mark = place4;
else
{
    goto jump5;
}
jump5:
    if (choice == 5 && place5 == '5')

        mark = place5;
    else
    {
        goto jump6;
    }
    jump6:
        if (choice == 6 && place6 == '6')

            mark = place6;
        else
        {
            goto jump7;
        }
        jump7:
            if (choice == 7 && place7 == '7')

                mark = place7;
            else
            {
                goto jump8;
            }
            jump8:
                if (choice == 8 && place8 == '8')

                    mark = place8;
                else
                {
                    goto jump9;
                }
                jump9:
                    if (choice == 9 && place9 == '9')

                        mark = place9;
                    else
                    {
                        goto jump;
                    }
                    jump:
printf("   %c     |      %c      |     %c    \n", &place, &place2, &place3);
printf("   %c     |      %c      |     %c    \n", &place4, &place5, &place6);
printf("   %c     |      %c      |     %c    \n", &place7, &place8, &place9);










}
```

ive been trying to find an awnser but cant find anyone with this problem.

Comment: In you case adding `&` to the variables in `printf()` results in *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: `goto` is a terrible idea in general, and `goto` a label that is the very next statement in the program is completely redundant.  If you don't want to do anything except go on to the next line, simply omit the `else` clause.

Comment: If you are new to C, don't use `goto`. Only use it when you have enough experience to understand when it results in better code.

Comment: All comparisons with `place ==` etc. are useless since none of these variables ever change.

Comment: `&` is used for address of the variable & corresponding format specifier is `%p`. Apart from this, you have made `mark` a `char *` instead of `char` due to use of double-quotes.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. Always.

Comment: David already got it. You're using "addresses" in memory of the variables place to place9 instead of their values. Remove the & signs and you're good to go. Also I'd suggest making a 2D char array for a simpler representation and access ;)

Comment: you don't need to use goto here , you can pretty much delete every else statement when your if conditions are mutually exclusive , which they are here. 
goto can mess up the  flow of your program pretty badly , avoid it totally , there's always a better way to do the same thing without a goto

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `&` from the `place` variables. When you put an `&` symbol before a variable name, it returns a pointer to the variable. For `scanf`, you have to do that because `scanf` actually has to change the values of the variables, so you must pass by reference, which basically means that you pass pointers into the function. In `printf`, you pass by value since `printf` does not change the values of the variables.

Thus, the correct lines are:

```c
printf("   %c     |      %c      |     %c    \n", place, place2, place3);
printf("   %c     |      %c      |     %c    \n", place4, place5, place6);
printf("   %c     |      %c      |     %c    \n", place7, place8, place9);
```